# Redirect all index.html pages to subdirectory?

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an old site ported from WordPress to basic HTML (don't ask why) and every page is ending in the `subdirectory/index.html`.

This is causing some funky indexing issues, so I wanted to 301 all the `index.html` to its parent subdirectory.

So for instance, I would like my pages:

- `example.com/index.html` to 301 to `example.com/`
- `example.com/service/index.html` to 301 to `example.com/service/`
- `example.com/about-us/index.html` to 301 to `example.com/about-us`

etc, etc.

Comment: What do you mean "every page is ending in the subdirectory/index.html" ?
 That is what internal links look like?

Comment: Every URL in WordPress often ends in a `/` (depending on the permalink settings).  If you copy a WordPress website to static files using something like wget, you often get a ton of directories, each containing exactly one file: `index.html`.     Depending on your download crawler, the links may or may not actually point to `index.html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a couple of assumptions:

1. All your internal links must already point to the non-`index.html` URL, eg. `example.com/service/`. (However, since you state that "every page is ending in the `subdirectory/index.html`" and you are experiencing some "funky indexing issues, I wonder if this is the case?)
2. You are using `.htaccess` on Apache.

Try something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html
RewriteRule (.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The check against `THE_REQUEST` in the `RewriteCond` directive ensures that only direct requests from the client, that contain `index.html`, get redirected. `THE_REQUEST` server variable contains the first line of the request headers and does not get modified when the URL is rewritten. This avoids a potential redirect loop when mod_dir later issues a subrequest for `index.html` (the `DirectoryIndex` document) - although this shouldn't be an issue on Apache 2.2+.

However, this could be "simplified" further. The `RewriteCond` directive could be omitted if using the `NS` (`nosubreq`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive. The `NS` flag prevents the rule being processed on "subrequests". As mentioned above, when mod_dir rewrites the URL, it is considered a *subrequest*. So, by simply including the `NS` flag, we again avoid a redirect loop. So, the above directives could be replaced with a single `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteRule (.*)index\.php$ /$1 [NS,R=301,L]
```

---

If you also have a canonical www to non-www redirect then it may be optimal to include the above rule first and specify the canonical absolute domain in the `RewriteRule` substitution (thus avoiding a potential double redirect). For example:

```
:
RewriteRule (.*)index\.html$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> `example.com/about-us/index.html` to 301 to `example.com/about-us`

I assume the missing trailing slash on your last example was a typo? The above rule includes a trailing slash (which is required). Omitting the trailing slash introduces additional complexity.

Comment: Have you tested that the rewrite rule is compatible with Apache's DirectoryIndex?    The rewrite rule looks like it could work, but I've found that you usually have to use environment variables in similar situations to avoid infinite loops: [How to rewrite to a script and also redirect away from that script using .htaccess while avoiding infinite loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340785/how-to-rewrite-to-a-script-and-also-redirect-away-from-that-script-using-htacce)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, this does seem to work OK in my testing. It does require the `DirectoryIndex` to be set correctly (which I assume it must be if URLs like `example.com/service/` are already working ok). The check against `THE_REQUEST` ensures it should only match the initial request (not the subsequent subrequest that results when mod_dir rewrites back to `index.html` - the DirectoryIndex) thus avoiding a redirect loop. This is a bit like your environment variable check. This example could even be "simplified" further into a one-liner by using the `NS` flag. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller However, this example is a bit different to your question over on SO. You are manually rewriting all requests to a single file (this isn't considered a "subrequest", it's simply an "internal rewrite"), so you wouldn't be able to make use of the `NS` flag, unlike in the example above. When mod_dir internally rewrites the request to the directory index (as opposed to you manually rewriting the request with mod_rewrite) then it is a "subrequest" and can be trapped with the `NS` (`nosubreq`) flag.

Comment: This is where your technical knowledge of Apache's internals well surpasses mine.  :)   I'll have to keep your `THE_REQUEST` trick in mind next time I need something like this.  It sounds easier than the environment variable.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think the environment variable method is still a good solution (although you don't need to manually set the env var, you can use Apache's `REDIRECT_STATUS` instead - [I added an answer to your question over on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44509367/369434)). Whether you use `THE_REQUEST` or `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS` here is largely a matter of preference I think, but there may be other problems where `THE_REQUEST` is more suited.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I accepted your answer there because it is much more thorough and actually contains enough code.